# How can I close a login form and show the main form without my application closing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms in my project (Login and Main).

What I'm trying to accoomplish is, if the login is successful, I must show the Main form and close the Login form.

I have this method in Login form that closes the Login form when the login is successful. But the Main form doesn't show.

```
public void ShowMain()
{
    if(auth()) // a method that returns true when the user exists.
    {             
        var main = new Main();
        main.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid login details.");
    }         
}
```

I tried hiding the Login form if the login process is successful. But it bothers me because I know while my program is running the login form is still there too, it should be closed right?

What should be the right approach for this?
Thanks...

Comment: try calling this.Close() in the end and not as first operation

Comment: same, the whole application closes.

Comment: you can try , main.ShowDialog(); instead of main.Show();.  it should work fine. since ShowDialog is modeless form.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The reason your main form isn't showing is because once you close the login form, your application's message pump is shut down, which causes the entire application to exit. The [Windows message loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows) is tied to the login form because that's the one you have set as the startup form in your project properties. Look in your "Program.cs" file, and you'll see the responsible bit of code: `Application.Run(new LoginForm())`. Check out the documentation for that method here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx), which explains this in greater detail.

The best solution is to move the code out of your login form into the "Program.cs" file. When your program first starts, you'll create and show the login form as a modal dialog (which runs on a separate message loop and blocks execution of the rest of your code until it closes). When the login dialog closes, you'll check its `DialogResult` property to see if the login was successful. If it was, you can start the main form using `Application.Run` (thus creating the main message loop); otherwise, you can exit the application without showing any form at all. Something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    LoginForm fLogin = new LoginForm();
    if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add what should be written in Login form also?

Comment: @r.hamd just set DialogResult = DialogResult.OK after you call this.Close() in LoginForm

Comment: In 2021 This is still the cleanest of the options available. The advice to launch the login dialog after the form is created in many other responses is an anti-pattern and is only useful for applications that allow unauthenticated user interactions.

Answer (score 11):

I would do this the other way round.

In the OnLoad event for your Main form show the Logon form as a dialog.  If the dialog result of that is OK then allow Main to continue loading, if the result is authentication failure then abort the load and show the message box.

**EDIT** Code sample(s)

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();

    LogonForm logon = new LogonForm();

    if (logon.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Handle authentication failures as necessary, for example:
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to show the LogonForm from the Main method in program.cs, something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    LogonForm logon = new LogonForm();

    Application.Run(logon);

    if (logon.LogonSuccessful)
    {
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

In this example your LogonForm would have to expose out a LogonSuccessful bool property that is set to true when the user has entered valid credentials

Comment: Is it ok also to initially hide the Main form. Then show it when login is successful?

Comment: but in this way if you have some logic in the load of main form it will be executed anyway... and you are changing the forms showing workflow from other forms... sounds a bit dirty and spaghetti programming.

Comment: Why load the main form at all until the login is successful?

Comment: 1.When I make login form to show on form load. It still show the main form on the background. And when I add code "this.hide();". Now it's work and look more professional.

2. But when I look at other comment the others comment that shouldn't do the main form process until user login success so I use your 2nd example code and It's work too. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

This is my solution. Create ApplicationContext to set mainform of application and change mainform when you want to open new form and close current form.

### Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    static ApplicationContext MainContext = new ApplicationContext();

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        MainContext.MainForm = new Authenticate();
        Application.Run(MainContext);
    }

    public static void SetMainForm(Form MainForm)
    {
        MainContext.MainForm = MainForm;
    }

    public static void ShowMainForm()
    {
        MainContext.MainForm.Show();
    }
}
```

When login process is complete.

```
private void BtLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Login Process Here.

        Program.SetMainForm(new Portal());
        Program.ShowMainForm();

        this.Close();
    }
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

It's simple.

Here is the code.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
        //creating instance of main form
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();

        // creating event handler to catch the main form closed event
        // this will fire when mainForm closed
        mainForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(mainForm_FormClosed);
        //showing the main form
        mainForm.Show();
        //hiding the current form
        this.Hide();
  }

  // this is the method block executes when main form is closed
  void mainForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
  {
       // here you can do anything

       // we will close the application
       Application.Exit();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the most elegant solution.

```
private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
    this.Hide();
    mainForm.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution, your problem is that your whole application closes when your login form closes right? If so, then **go to your projects properties and on the Application Tab change the shutdown mode to "When last form closes"** that way you can use Me.close without closing the whole program

Comment: That's only available for VB.Net projects.

Answer (score 2):

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Login();
    } 

    private static bool logOut;

    private static void Login()
    {
        LoginForm login = new LoginForm();
        MainForm main = new MainForm();
        main.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(main_FormClosed);
        if (login.ShowDialog(main) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Run(main);
            if (logOut)
                Login();
        }
        else
            Application.Exit();
    }

    static void main_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        logOut= (sender as MainForm).logOut;
    }
}

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private void btnLogout_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //timer1.Stop();
        this.logOut= true;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should do it the other way round:

Load the `mainform` first and in its `onload` event show your `loginform` with `showdialog()` which will prevent `mainform` from showing until you have a result from the `loginform`

**EDIT**:
As this is a *login* form and if you do not need any variables from your `mainform` (*which is bad design in practice*), you should really implement it in your program.cs as Davide and Cody suggested.

Comment: I can't really imagine a case where one form should require *variables* from another form.

Comment: @Cody: so, it makes your answer the inevitable. You know I just feel sometimes you need to provide something based on the OP's initial code/thought for them to better understand what the problem is..

Comment: @Bolu: The point wasn't so much "I'm right, you're wrong", but rather that one form accessing another form's variables is *always* bad design in an object-oriented language. I think it's important the OP understand this as well.

Comment: @Cody, True. Like OP asked how can I eat my apple as I can't cut the apple with my pen, my answer is like: "use a knife" whereas your answer makes more sense: "you don't need to cut it, just eat it"....

Answer (score 0):

I think a much better method is to do this in the Program.cs file where you usually have Application.Run(form1), in this way you get a cleaner approach, Login form does not need to be coupled to Main form, you simply show the login and if it returns true you display the main form otherwise the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void ShowMain()
    {
        if(auth()) // a method that returns true when the user exists.
        { 
            this.Close();
            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Main));
            t.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid login details.");
        }         
    }
   [STAThread]
   public void Main()
   {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Main());

   }
```

You must call the new form in a diferent thread apartment, if I not wrong, because of the call system of windows' API and COM interfaces.

One advice: this system is high insecure, because you can change the if condition (in MSIL) and it's "a children game" to pass out your security. You need a stronger system to secure your software like obfuscate or remote login or something like this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: of the series how to make easy things difficult :DD

Comment: No, WinForms is not designed to work with a multi-threaded apartment model. I'm not really sure what you're advocating here, or how this code would work. Where does the `ShowMain` method ever get called? Why do you need to create a new thread at all?

Comment: I've never said windows works in a mutithread model, where i've said this? Because the restriction in windows to get a windows form, the API under COM technologies needs to get a SINGLE thread apartment for differents programs execution. If you close the login thread, all forms will be closed. This get the main form active. ShowMain is called by Application.Run()... Do you call a ShowForm in a windowsform application when it start? please...

Answer (score 0):

best way for show login for and close login form before login successfully put login form in FrmMain after InitializeComponent.

```
 public FrmMain()
 {
      FrmSplash FrmSplash = new FrmSplash();
      FrmSplash.ShowDialog();

      InitializeComponent();
      //Login Section
 {
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void ShowMain()
  {
       if(auth()) // a method that returns true when the user exists.
       {        
         this.Hide();
         var main = new Main();
         main.Show();
       }
      else
       {
              MessageBox.Show("Invalid login details.");
        }         
   }
```

Comment: While apparently correct, this question already had *several* correct answers with nearly identical code. This answer doesn't really add any value to the question.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 private void cmdLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUserName.Text == "admin" || txtPassword.Text == "1")
        {

            FrmMDI mdi = new FrmMDI();
            mdi.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else {

            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Credentials", "Library Management System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
```

and when you  exit the Application you can use

```
 Application.Exit();
```

Comment: This would be a bad idea if you really want to close it, cause the form will still stay in memory...

Answer (score -1):

Evan the post is too old i like to give you a trick to do this if you wants to show splash/login screen and when the progress bar of splash screen get certain value/or successful login happen and closed the splash/login then re show the main form, frm-main will be the startup form not frm-spalash

in frm-main

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    { 
        frmSplash frm = new frmSplash();
        frm.Show(); // new splash screen will shows
        this.Opacity=0; // will hide your main form
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
```

in the frm-Splash

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 int cnt = progressBar1.Value;

    switch (cnt)
    {
        case 0:
                //Do sum stuff
            break;
        case 100:

            this.Close(); //close the frm-splash
            frmMain.ActiveForm.Opacity = 100; // show the frm-main

            break;
    }

    progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value+1;
}
```

if you use it for login form

```
private void btlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 bool login = false;

    //try your login here 
    //connect your database or whatever
    //and then when it success update login variable as true

        if(login == true){

            this.Close(); //close the frm-login
            frmMain.ActiveForm.Opacity = 100; // show the frm-main

        }else{
              //inform user about failed login
        }
}
```

note that i use a **timer** and a **progress bar** to manipulate the actions you don't need those two it just for sake of complete answer only, hope this helps

Comment: This feels more of a hack than a solution. The biggest issue that we should be trying to avoid is spawning UI process `frm.Show()` from within the constructor of the main form.

Answer (score -1):

1.Go to MainMenu Design properties> Go to my events[image]

2.Click MainMenu event Shown and show LoginForm[image]

3.Leave MainMenu as the First run in Program.cs