# close windows form works on a form but not on another one

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2012

I have crated a windows form application.

VS2012 created a `form1` form to me

then I crated a second form called `Main`

there is a button on `form1` form to go to `Main` form

when I run the application using vs2012, and then I click the `x` button at the top right of form **form1**, the form close and I can start working on vs. but the problem is when I click the x button at the top right of the form **Main**, I can't start working on VS, but I need to click `Stop Debugging` red button in the vs in order to be able to type in vs.

so my question is when I give this application to my customers, and when the click the x button at the top right of the form, I need the application to close totally, I don't need them to go the task manager and close the application from it.

Comment: That is because Main is still running... It **owns ** `form1` by the sounds of things. You therefore need to properly manage lifetime of app and close all forms before app will exit.

Comment: The program runs until either the Application is stopped  by `Application.Exit();`or the Form that is started in the `Program.cs` file is closed. Other forms do not matter.

Comment: Please provide some sample code to show the flow of logic in your program.

Comment: @Belogix thanks for the description. I got the idea

Comment: @TaW thanks for the description.

Comment: @Kjartan the guys below gave me the correct answer, though the flow is very simple, just one button to go to the other form and a back button to go back to the start up form

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898085/to-close-c-sharp-forms-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application starts with `Form 1`, when you close it you are closing the application. `Main` is just a form, when you close it you are closing the form. What you need to is, go to `FormClosing` event of `Main` form and add

> Application.Exit();

Comment: your solution works perfectly. however the other guy told me to use `System.Envirenement.Exiit(0)` which one is better pelease? Sorry I can't +1 to you because I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Here is a detailed article: http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx

Comment: System.Envirenement.Exit(0); quite evrything related to your app wich means anything that your app opend will but closed it will the process ;)

Comment: @Youness that is a pain, please tell me what is the good one. I just need to close the application. the application write to some csv files

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec i don't think it will make difference in your application.  Your question depends on the program. You can just the code i gave.

Comment: he is right for you it would'nt make a défference you can use wich one you want

Comment: Quote: _Application.Exit()....As a general guideline, use this call if you have called System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run._ This applies to your program.

Answer (score 0):

got to the **FormClosing** event and put this code :

```
System.Envirenement.Exit(0);
```

Comment: where is that? a property in vs ?

Comment: its an Event whene a jsut select your form and got to the proprietes tab and click events (the yellow thender ;) ) there look for FormClosing double click the empty field near it and a method will be added write that code int it

Comment: Don't do that. It is a hard exit, requiring special rights. See the docs!

Answer (score 0):

What do you do with `form1` when you go to `Main`? If you just hide it in order to show the other, then close the other one, while just keeping `form1` hidden, then `form1` will naturally still be running, even if `Main` is closed.

Sounds like the logical thing to do would be to go back to `form1` from `Main` when you close the latter - otherwise, you can close both using `Application.Exit(0)` on the appropriate event.

In either case, it would be easier to answer this if you had provided some actual code.

**Update:**

You could also use `System.Environment.Exit(0)`, but that might require more privileges, which might or might not affect your situation. Again - some code would be helpful.

In regard to your comments, see [this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146080/closing-applications) about termination options.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but should I use `System.Envirenement.Exit(0)` or `Application.Exit();` please?

Comment: I believe `dispose` will only close the window - not sure, but it might not stop the application completely (test it and see what happens!). `Application.Exit()` should be fine; it should stop your program, like you want. Also, see my update - this has already been answered quite well on SO.

Comment: My pleasure! PS: Feel free to upvote or mark an answer as your "accepted answer" if it solves your problem ;)

Comment: Sorry I am not able to upvote since I don't have enough reputation for that. Plus, I had to accept the first correct answer. I wish I could accept more. many thanks for the efforts

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because your `Form1` form still running(hidden).
If you use `Form1` only for open your `Main` form. Then delete `Form1` and set `Main` as StartUp form in Properties of your proejct:
`Application -> StartUp form`

After this when you close `Main` form application will be closed properly

If you use `Form1` then you need close `Form1` too after you close `Main` form.
Use `FormClosed` eventhandler for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Right click on **Main** form -> Properties 
on the **Event**  tab choose **FormClosing** event
and write this code

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
           System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```