# Is it possible to have the program itself not close when the main form closes?

Tags: c#, forms

I know it was possible to do so in VB.NET, but I can't find out how in C#. How would it do it here?

Comment: How did you do it in VB.NET? Most of the time, there's a direct correspondence to C#...

Comment: @Cameron it's a setting in the Application tab. That's what my friend (who is REALLY good at VB.NET) said so, anyway.

Comment: @Minicl55: Did he just tell you or showed you also.

Comment: @Cameron He said so. But he's made a program EXACTLY like the one I'm making, and he said that's how he did it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Working with mutliple Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769193/c-sharp-working-with-mutliple-forms)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `Main` routine (the Entry Point for the program) in `Program.cs` (by default) to use [`Application.Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900.aspx) instead of `Application.Run(Form)`.

Alternatively, you can specify your own `ApplicationContext` and override [`OnMainFormClosed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.onmainformclosed.aspx) to provide different behavior than automatically shutting down.

Comment: @Minicl55 Overriding ApplicationContext with your own lets you do anything you want.  Alternatively, you could just have the main form exist, but stay hidden until your secondary form makes it visible...

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the form and place an icon in the system tray.  Override the closing event and hide it instead, then to show it when user clicks on the tray icon for example.

More info on the closing event and how to cancel the close: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It would be enough to start a new `Thread` to do what you are suggesting, but I'm not sure that this would satisfy your goal.

EDIT:

An example of a technique I'm suggesting:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace HangApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            Runner r = new Runner();
        }

        class Runner
        {
            internal Runner()
            {
                _start = DateTime.Now;
                Thread t = new Thread(ThreadStart);
                t.Start();
            }
            DateTime _start;
            void ThreadStart()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    //  some stuff to do
                    if (ExitConditionMet())
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            bool ExitConditionMet()
            {
                //  will run the app for 5 seconds after main form was closed
                return (DateTime.Now - _start).TotalSeconds > 5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, code above is only a demonstration, one should never:

- do a thread that does nothing in a tight loop
- do a thread start in a class constructor

Comment: In the current form of the question TITLE, they are direct answer to it.

Comment: No, it actually does not answer that question either. Really.

Comment: @minitech I think the suggestion was to put your logic into a separate (non background) thread, which would keep running even after the form closes.

Comment: It actually does.  I even tried it.  I know it since I occasionally suffer from stray unterminated threads.  :)

Comment: I realize that, but I don't think that's what the question was asking. (Well, at least I *didn't*. Now I'm not so sure.)