# Closing an unrelated .NET form inside another form in Winforms

Tags: .net, winforms

I am trying to understand the behavior of the following code in a WinForms application.
I have two forms - Form1 and Form2. When i close Form1 from inside Form2, even Form2 gets closed. I have ensured that they both  have the Owner property set to null.

Can anyone explain why Form2 gets closed as well from the code below?
Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 f1;
    public Form2(Form1 f1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.f1 = f1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        f1.Close();         
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
static void Main()
    {           
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Size = new Size(0, 0);
        f1.Show();           

        Form2 f2 = new Form2(f1);
        f2.ShowDialog();            

        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

When the Button on Form2 is clicked both Form1 and Form2 get closed. I have also ensured that the button is not the okbutton or cancelbutton for Form2. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: what is MainForm() standing for? Delete the line _f1.Show();_ and replace Application.Run(f1);

Comment: MainForm is an unrelated Form which starts up the application in a standard way. I am interested in why the two forms behave that way before calling Application.Run(). If Form2 is called inside Application.Run() then the behavior is as per one's expectation

Comment: Then, move those form showing codes into MainForm_Load

Comment: I am trying to understand a (possibly) quirky behavior. I am not trying to make some code work. So, I would appreciate if you could explain why this happens

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent the app from terminating when I close the startup form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769193/how-do-i-prevent-the-app-from-terminating-when-i-close-the-startup-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form1 closes because you have created a new Form1 and passed it to Form2, and inside Form2, you are closing the Form1. And just because Form2 is a DialogForm, and created after Form1, it is supposed as a DialogForm of Form1, so if Form1 is closed, the DialogForm is closed too. It is an expected behaviour rather than a quirky one.

Either show it using

```
f2.Show();
```

or show the Form2 dialog form inside MainForm (by passing f1 to Form2 via MainForm), so Form1 closes but not Form2.

Update:

Try this in your Program.cs and you will see that Application's MainWindow is closed after you close Form1.

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Size = new Size(0, 0);
f1.Show();

MessageBox.Show(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle.ToString());

Form f2 = new Form2(f1);

MessageBox.Show(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle.ToString());

f2.ShowDialog();

MessageBox.Show(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle.ToString());

Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Would you know why this happens before Application.Run and not after? i.e. why is Form2 considered Form1's DialogForm? And how can we check this? Is there a property which allows us to inspect this? Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Form1 becomes the MainWindow of your Application since it is called first, and if your main window is closed, Form2 is closed too since it is created after Form1 and ShowDialog can not be modal-less (afaik).