# when the MainForm is closed

Tags: c#, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I prevent the app from terminating when I close the startup form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769193/how-do-i-prevent-the-app-from-terminating-when-i-close-the-startup-form)

How can i stop the application from ending when the main form is closed? 
I want to check if the `Application.OpenForms.Count == 1` and only then close the application if its true. So I want to close the app when the last of the forms is closed.

Comment: Don't close the main form - hide it.

Comment: Pass an `ApplicationContext` to `Application.Run` and control app lifetime that way

Comment: I'll still prefer Oded's answer.. simple to implement

Comment: @CofiPetrovic - Have you tried hiding the main form?  Is this new development or modification of existing code?  From the description, I'd say there's code smell.

Comment: @Aniket It depends on the main form.  If it's a large form with lots of content you can be holding onto a lot of memory needlessly by doing that, or leaking other resources that the form is holding onto such as file handles.

Comment: Sorry about the comment.