# Hidden form not closing

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a C# `Form`, where you have `Form1` shown at the start, and when you press `Go` you are taken to `Form2`. `Form1` is hidden and `Form2` is shown.

Now when you exit `form2`, the whole application should be closed. I am using `Application.Exit()` when I press the exit button.
I am facing problems if the user presses <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>ALT+F4</kbd> or `RightClick->Close`. 
The form will close but the hidden form will stay opened.

How can I fix that? When I press one of these control button, for all hidden forms to also close?

I tried `form1_Close` and `Form1_Closing` function but they didn't seem to work.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're only hiding Form1 and not closing it?

Comment: Is there an option to go back to `Form1` or is closing `Form2` and exiting the program the only option?

Comment: Just close the Form1 instance instead of hiding it.  With [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10769349/17034) to stop that from terminating your app.  Now it is simple and fail-safe.

Comment: i need to hide it and keep it in the backgroud for later use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Hide();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
form2.Show();
```

This will close `Form1` when you close `Form2`.  If the user presses <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or `RightClick -> Close` on `Form2` The `Form2` and the hidden `Form1` will close.

Comment: Perfect, what i needed!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [FormClosed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx) on Form2 to exit the application.

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     Application.Exit();
}
```