# Close Window in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I want to close a windows which is currently shown.
But when I call `Close()`, it only hide the window. 
And the memory length still grows instead of decreasing.

I also use this answer to fix this problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34651426/9135351

but it doesn't work.

Here is my code to show a new Window and close the shown Window

**C#**

```
private void Home_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   new HomeContentView().Show(); //Open Home window
   Close(); //Close current window
   GC.Collect(); //Realease
}
```

**Xaml**

```
 <Button
     ToolTip="Home"
     Click="Home_Click"
     Cursor="Hand"
     Background="Transparent"
     BorderBrush="Transparent"
     Margin="0,0,221,0"
     HorizontalAlignment="Right"
     Width="48" Height="48"
     VerticalAlignment="Top">

     <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Home" Width="37" Height="38" 
     Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
 </Button>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? It's a bit impossible to guess what you have already done..

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894863/wpf-increase-memory-each-time-open-and-close-window ?

Comment: Here is the code to open new Window and close the current \n `new HomeContentView().Show();` `Application.Current.Windows[1].Close();`

Comment: No I didn't. I just saw. I will try and keep you informed

Comment: @DjordjeNedovic. I try to use `GC.collect`, but it doesn't work correctly. The memory is always growing

Comment: @2kFerd, can you please update your question by adding code? Maybe something else is responsible for memory growing

Comment: I do it. I add the both c# and xaml code

Comment: @2kFerd does 'HomeContentView' subscribe to any events on singletons or the like? If so those connections keep the view alive since there is still an active reference from the root to that object.

Comment: @Johannes, I don't get you. Could you explain your answer, please

Comment: When an observer subscribes to an event the subject has to keep a reference in order to notify. That reference keeps the observer alive. So if you have an event subscription in your 'HomeContentView' constructor it would not matter that you closed it it would stay alive and never be collected. WPF internally handles all it subscriptions correctly - when you implement them you need to watch out for that. I mention it because you are looking for a memory leak in c#.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes. I wonder if `static` field can keep the view alive too?

Comment: @2kFerd a static field should not keep any of the instances alive unless it tracks the instances like a static list of instances for example. it comes down to weather or not you can use the static field to navigate to an instance or not. A static integer would not be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

[`Close()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.close) should do the trick. Why can't you use the object created for the `Window` and `Close` that instead of accessing it from the `Application.Current.Windows`

```
var window = new HomeContentView(); 
window.Show(); // Shows window
window.Close(); // Closes window
```

Comment: The both do the same thing. Each time I use `Close()` or `Application.Current.Windows`, the visible window is closed but the memory grows until 433M. That's my problem.

Comment: If so, i believe there might be memory leak from some where else. I suggest you to use some profiling tools to understand better on this.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I will search again

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MyMethod()
    {
        var myWindow = this;
        var control = myWindow.Content;
        //do stuff
        control = null; // is that okay??
        myWindow.Close();
    }
```

Comment: could you add some explanation description to your answer?

Comment: I defined the function that received the current form and cut all the components inside it and then closed it.