# Closing an open Form from a Parent Form

Tags: c#

I am programming an applicaion with visual studio and c#. it has a Parent Form (FormParent) which is a MdiContainer and contains a toolstrip. the FormParent Conatins and a child Form (FormChild). So I open other Forms inside of it like FormUser.

Suppose I have a open FormUser, how can I close this FormUser when I click the toolstrip button ( for example the save one)?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33281583/2946329

Comment: Maybe: `Application.OpenForms.OfType<FormUser>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Focused)?.Close();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did This and worked

```
  FormUser obj = (FormUser)Application.OpenForms["FormUser"];                
  obj.Close();
```

also thank you to @JQSOFT answer with a little edit another solution is :

```
  Application.OpenForms.OfType<FormUser>().FirstOrDefault().Close();
```