# It exists a way to open a form and close a parent form from a User Control in Winforms C#?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-controls, parent

i'm developing an aplication in Winforms C#, this is my problem
I make a expandible menu to reuse in every of my forms but when I click the button I need to open a new form and close the parent form from a user control , but when I try to do it by calling my own function on the user control it sends a NullReferenceException

This is my function

```
public void abrirFormulario(Form formulario)
    {
        Form padre= this.FindForm();
        padre.Close();
        padre.Dispose();

        formulario.Show();
        formulario.Activate();
    }
```

And this is the button that calls this function (This button is located inside a panel)

```
private void btnOperadores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form operador = new frmControl_Operadores();
        abrirFormulario(operador);
    }
```

Hope you can help me

Comment: This is the correct way to close the form BTW https://stackoverflow.com/a/33281583/2946329

Comment: @SalahAkbari:  Instead of commenting, please add this link as an answer.

Comment: Both of you please consider flagging as duplicate.

Comment: It wasn't the answer but It helped me to have the right way, thanks