# How do I close a form after I open another form

Tags: c#, forms

So let's say I clicked a button and it's supposed to open a new form and close the current form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    Form2 AFormInstance = new Form2();
    AFormInstance.Show();
}
```

I tried `this.Close()` but what ended up happening was both forms closed. How do I open `Form2` and close `Form1`?

Comment: have you tried this.Close(); after you instantiate the new form and display it?

Comment: Yeah I tried placing my `this.Close()` call after I instantiated the new form. It still closed both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10769349/17034

Comment: Call this.Close(); AFTER AFormInstance.Show();

Answer (score 0):

If the parent of Button1 is Form1 you can use :

```
var formToBeClosed = ((sender as Button).Parent) as Form;
formToBeClosed.Close();
```

Answer (score -2):

Just switch some lines:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 AFormInstance = new Form2();
    AFormInstance.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Edit: On further thought: aren't you accidentally closing your main form?

Change the default code of program.cs to:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show();
        Application.Run();
    }
```

To close the application use:

```
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: will this not refer to the current instance therefore closing AFormInstance?

Comment: No. The eventhandler is on Form1, so it will close the form1 instance