# C# how to apply Exit code for all X mark button in every form?

Tags: c#, winforms, exit

I know this code can exit my application

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
```

But how to apply this code for all my form 
Let say I have a lot of form Do I have to put this code in every form?

Comment: When the main form exits, the application will end.

Comment: It really depends on what you need. If you want to close application on any from close, then yes you need to subscribe to `Form_Closing` event on each Form and perform this logic.

Comment: What about if my main form is a login form so user have to logout first and then close my application?

Comment: @HariPrasad you're right, but `Exit` won't raise the `Form_Closing` event, so have to use `Close`instead of `Exit`

Comment: If you do not have a good hierarchy between windows then it gets to be pretty confusing to the user how to properly end your app.  Do avoid hiding windows, that just makes it confusing to your code as well.  Another approach is to simply keep it running as long as there is *any* window.  [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10769349/17034).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this line inside a `static` method inside the `class` containing the `Main()`....that makes it somewhat modular, not much useful though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
this.close();
```

to close your currently active form. Similarly you can use it every form you want to close.

Comment: Does this kill my process in Task Manager?

Comment: @user33540:- Close method will free all the resources that are associated with the component and that is what I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

Refered to my comment you can call the `Close`-method and use `FormClosing`-event to close the other forms:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
        form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

In this example Form1 is your MainForm and if you close Form1 whether you use the `Close`-method or by closing the form by the default button the `FormClosing` event will be raised and all other forms will be closed too.

If you want to kill the current Process you can use this code:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

Answer (score 0):

In many windows forms projects I've worked we had a base form and all forms in our code inherited from this base form, so you can have a form like below and you just change the others forms to inherit from this one.

```
public partial class frmBase: Form
{
    public frmBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmBase_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }           
}
```