# How to close all open and hidden forms in C# with one button?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a Splash Screen to my program.

And when the splash end  , exec the code

```
this.Hide();
frmLogin o = new frmLogin();
o.show();
```

And it works but the splash screen go invisible and when i close the program by my custom exit button it's only closing the current form.
But my splash screen is still hidden and appears the app name to task manager.
How i can close that currently *opened* form and the **invisible** ones with my custom button ?

Comment: Use `Close()` instead of `Hide()`.

Comment: search how to use [Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i tried but it closes the both froms.

Comment: Just don't hide it and you don't have a problem.  That probably makes your app terminate, [that is easy to fix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10769349/17034).  Or simply don't make your splash screen or your login window the main window.

Answer (score 1):

You are launching your whole application from the splash screen form.

It would be better avoid this behaviour separating splash screen form from main form, and opening up from this last form the splash screen, as well as you have done with `frmLogin`.

However you can workaround this problem using `this.Hide()` and at the exit of the program using `Application.Exit()` within your "custom exit button" event.

Answer (score 1):

While in design view, select the `frmLogin` button.  On the right, the Properties window should update.  Select the `Events` tab.  Look for `FormClosing` in the list of events.  Select the right column and type a method name of your choice.  If you typed `xBtnPress`, the designer will generate a stub that will look like this:

```
private void xBtnPress(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {

}
```

If you wish to close your application upon this event, call `Application.Exit()` from within the event handler.