# Close a windows form but it still running in the task bar

Tags: c#

I am trying to close a winform "Splash Screen" and running another form.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rectangleShape2.Width += 5;
        if (rectangleShape2.Width >= 473)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            HomeScreen H = new HomeScreen();
            H.ShowDialog();
            //to close current form
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that: the Splash Screen form still working in the task bar
how can i close it and hide it from the task bar?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `H.Show()` instead of `H.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed it does not work. The Splash screen and the new form is closed

Comment: Then you must be having the "splash screen" as the startup form. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10769193/4934172).

Comment: If that's the case, you can use some help from the answers to that question. However, it's not a good idea to have the splash screen as your startup form so you might want to tweak your logic a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

hope this solution will help you

```
void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {

     //after 3 sec stop the timer

     tmr.Stop();

     //display mainform

     Mainform mf = new Mainform();

     mf.Show();

     //hide this form

     this.Hide();

 }

Double-click on the FormClosed Event and add this Code:
private void Mainform_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)

{

     //exit application when form is closed

     Application.Exit();

}
```

Comment: Splash Screen is my startup form ! So it will closed the application from the first time every time

Answer (score 0):

Try To replace

```
this.Hide()
```

from

```
this.Close()
```

its working for me