# Closing of all Previous Forms and Opening of New Form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How to `Close` background Forms whenever a new form is opened in Windows Forms C#?

1. It should not be the specific form to be closed.
2. It should close all the background forms whenever a form is opened.

Comment: Do you have a parent form that opens the new form?

Comment: `foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms) form.Close();` (in case of WinForms)

Comment: Yes, it has a Parent form @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani

Comment: Will you please elaborate still more.. @ Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko  Wouldn't this also terminate the application (closing the starting Form)? Maybe with a `if (form != [MainForm]) (...) else { [MainForm].Hide(); }` (with means to show it back).

Comment: Jimi: yes `Hide()` may be a better option. Not necessary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769193/how-do-i-prevent-the-app-from-terminating-when-i-close-the-startup-form

Comment: Just never use Hide(), use Close() instead.  But you have to tweak the Program class a bit to ensure that your app does not terminate.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769349/17034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches.

First is using `Application.OpenForms` like this:

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if(Form is YourMainFormClassName) //Check if current form is your main form and do not close it since your app would close. You can use .Hide() if you want
        return;

    form.Close();
}
```

Other approach is using `List` but you cannot do `List<Form>` because when removing you will have problem if you want to remove specific form and you go like `yourList.Remove(this)` it will remove all items with class of that form. Of course it will happen only if you open one form multiple times but to avoid that we will use `Form.Tag` property.

`An Object that contains data about the control. The default is null`

So we will use it to store our `Id` of the form.

So now when we prepared system let's write it:

First we need `List<Form>` that is accessible from all classes so we will create it like `public static` property.

```
public static class Settings //Class is also static
{
    public static List<Form> OpenedForms = new List<Form>();

    public static int MaxIdOfOpenedForm() //With this method we check max ID of opened form. We will use it later
    {
        int max = -1;
        foreach(Form f in OpenedForms)
        {
            if(Convert.ToInt32(f.Tag) > max)
                max = Convert.ToInt32(f.Tag);
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static void RemoveSpecificForm(Form form) //Remove specific form from list
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < OpenedForms.Count; i++)
        {
            if((OpenedForms[i] as Form).Tag == form.Tag)
            {
                OpenedForms.Remove(form);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void CloseAllOpenedForms()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < OpenedForms.Count; i++)
        {
            OpenedForms.Remove(OpenedForms[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have list but need to populate it every time we open new form so we will do it like this:

```
public partial class YourForm
{
    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        this.Tag = Settings.MaxIdOfOpenedForm() + 1; //We are setting Tag of newly opened form
        Settings.OpenedForms.Add(this); //Adding new form to opened forms.
    }
}
```

And when we close form we need to remove form from list:

```
private void YourFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RemoveSpecificForm(this);
}
```

and when we set this up just call `CloseAllOpenedForms()`.

This method could have some improvements in performance but this is basic and you expand it further.

Answer (score 0):

well as only one form can be active and in the foreground, so when openening a new form you can close the previous one:

In your main form:

```
Form previous_form = null;
```

and when creating any form:

```
if( previous_form != null)
    previous_form.Close();
SomeForm someform = new SomeForm();
previsous_form = some_form;
someform.Show();
```

Comment: Hi I want to close background forms but it should not specify this form or that form to be closed. @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani

Comment: well you want to close backgronud forms when a new form is opened, when a new form is opened all previous forms will be in background. so opening each form you should close the previous (that will go to the background)

Comment: But why should i specify the previous form, because it may have any number of form at background...@Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani

Comment: Is there any solution...please send me it.

Comment: @SouravKumarDas  If you have more than one Form to close, you need to keep a List of those references somewhere. Or close all forms in `Application.OpenForms` except your starting Form (the one run in `Program.cs`). It doesn't look like a worderful design, though.