# How to check WindowsState (Minimized & Foreground) of a ShowDialog Form?

Tags: c#

I want to check the windowstate of a form called main.cs which is opened by `form1.cs` as showdialog while `form1.cs` is hidden. I need this to create a tray and hide it in taskbar.

But nothing happens

I saw many solutions and I'm able to follow them, but only in a Form not in a `ShowDialog` of Form.

Thank you all.

```
private void form3_Resize (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        ShowIcon = false;
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
    }
}

private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     ShowInTaskbar = true;
    notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}

private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Application minimized";
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "deine mudder hatte recht...!"; 
}
```

Comment: A dialog cannot be hidden.  If you try anyway then it will automatically close.

Comment: ok, but why doesnt recognize the eventhandler the windowstate ?

Comment: You can't get an event from a form object that no longer exists.  Stop using ShowDialog() to get ahead, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769349/17034) for a better way.

Comment: Ah, Thank you very much. I will try it :)

Comment: I have used ShowDialog because i cant close form 1 but now it works with the eventhandler of main.cs   and  Application.Exit(); now i can open the main.cs with main.show(); and use eventhandlers in there.... biggest thanks to you