# Form refresh method duplicates....leaves old form open

Tags: c#

```
          Form= new form();

          Form.showDialog();

          This.close();
```

The new form opens but the this.close doesn't seem to activate. So now the new form is open but the old form is still there.

Note I am trying to close and open a new instance of the same form.

Comment: `Form.ShowDialog` Shows the form as a modal dialog box.

Comment: Opening the same form again and closing the the existing one seems a little brittle, even if you make this non modal seems it  like this could be done a better way. Why not just change your form dynamically? thats to say, what ever you do when opening the new form can probably be done in the existing one

Comment: Not sure if we are on the same track here but what I really want to do is refresh this form after I have completed a transaction.. wipe the existing data from all textbox etc...it's a lot of textbox and listbox and other controls so doing a clear or reset for each individual will be ....

Comment: Don't use ShowDialog when you did not intend to create a dialog.  If Show() makes your app terminate too soon, the most typical reason to get this wrong, then [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769193/how-do-i-prevent-the-app-from-terminating-when-i-close-the-startup-form).

Comment: How can I use show() keep my main form open but blocked from user ...make only new form usable untill closed? Thanks for the help I really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Form.ShowDialog` is a blocking call. This means that until it returns, the code after it won't run (and if that's on the UI thread, your application will appear unresponsive). From the [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8):

> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your application. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

You probably want `Form.Show` instead, to get a window without blocking. You haven't described your full use case, but showing something else and closing yourself is a very strange thing to do, guessing there is a better way to solve your problem as well.

Comment: Yes sorry if my question was a bit vague am a bit new to this ...yes I am trying to open the new form while keeping the main form open but blocked....I mean it works fine with .show but . Show doesn't give the option to block the main form.

Comment: I think I will just take the long rout and clear the textbox one at a time 

Comment: @RickalHamilton Stuff like this (clearing forms out) is way simpler with Data Binding in WPF. Unless you have a hard requirement to use WinForms, you might consider upgrading to the state of the art :)