# Close form if is another Form with same name Opened C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to close a form if it is already opened, this form is the main of the application, so if I close all the instances of this form, the application ends. I am trying to look for if that form is opened, and I find it, close it if it is more than one opened:

With this I get the instances opened with the name "Main":

```
int nPrincOpen = openForms
 .OfType<Form>()
 .Where(form => String.Equals(form.Name, "Main"))
 .ToList()
 .Count();
```

And with this I close these forms, but I close all the forms:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nPrincOpen - 1; i++)
{
         Application.OpenForms
    .OfType<Form>()
    .Where(form => String.Equals(form.Name, "Main"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(form => form.Close());           
}
```

**How could I close all the forms except one using link?**

Comment: is there a particular one you want to keep open or just any one of them.. if its just anyone, change you for loop to stop before you remove the last one `i < nPrincOpen - 2`

Comment: @Dave ok but the problems comes using link because I am closing all the forms called Main. So how can I close all the forms with this name except 1?

Comment: Add .Take(Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().Where(form => String.Equals(form.Name, "Main")).Count-1) before.ToList()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769349/17034

Answer (score 1):

Leave the first form open.

```
Application.OpenForms
.OfType<Form>()
.Where(form => String.Equals(form.Name, "Main"))
.Skip(1)
.ToList()
.ForEach(form => form.Close());
```