# How to open Form2 and close Form1 in the same time by C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem trying to open form 2 from form 1 and close form 1, and I have tried these solutions and can't find the right one:
Solution 1:-

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
            this.Close(); //close Form1
```

Solution 2:-
in file Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MyApplicationContext context = new MyApplicationContext();
        Application.Run(context);
    }
    public class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
    {
        private Form1 form1 = new Form1();

        public MyApplicationContext()
        {
            form1 = new Form1();
            form1.Show();
        }
    }
```

and in Form1.cs

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.Show();
            this.Close();
```

This solution works but after closing the applications, I find that it still works in the background.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are forms 1 and 2? Like a login form and a main form?

Comment: Exactly like that, Form1 Login and Form2 the main form.
@CaiusJard

Comment: Swap it around then; don't make your login form be the primary form that `Application.Run`s. Have the main form show the login form as a dialog

Comment: This sounds like a `splash screen` - try searching here on SO for that.

Comment: I tried that solution but it doesn't work, can you please write your solutions as an answer to the question and not comment so that I can give you a point ^_^?
@CaiusJard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769193/how-do-i-prevent-the-app-from-terminating-when-i-close-the-startup-form/10769349#10769349

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
       this.Hide();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        form2.Show();
```

Comment: I am sorry for the last comment, and Big Thank you for your answer ^_^ .