# How do I close the whole application when I close a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms in my application, Login and Dashboard. After the login the dashboard form is loaded and login "closes" with `this.Hide`. If I close the dashboard with the X button the application continues to run but nothing shows.

Comment: this.close instead of this.hide?

Comment: When `Dashboard` closes, also close `Login`, so the app exists. Or, make `Dashboard` the starting Form, so when it closes the app also closes. Or do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10769193/7444103). Or handle a custom ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Form2 [Dashboard] events.

```
    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        // when form closed
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // before form close
        Application.Exit();
    }
```