# Open Form with FormClosing event

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to open a Form (Form1) when click on "X" and FormClosing event run on another Form (For ex. Form4).

I try with:

```
private void Form4_FormClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.Show();
}
```

But don't run.
Someone can help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769193/how-do-i-prevent-the-app-from-terminating-when-i-close-the-startup-form

Comment: Are there any other issues with your program?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you exactly call the Form.

If you call it via Program.cs like this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        Application.Run(new Form4());
    }
```

and then close the Form4, everything will get disposed, which means also your Form1 will get called and then instantly disposed again.

You should handle it via Main() instead:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        Application.Run(new Form4());
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Now Form1 will be called, after Form4 closed.

Comment: You're making a pretty far-reaching assumption here, that the OP's intent would be to exit the application they're in and start an entirely new one with a different `Form` class as the main window. Now, granted, the question isn't the clearest, but it seems far more likely that the objective is to navigate between various "views" within the _same_ application than to spawn a brand new one.

Comment: You are indeed right, I am just working with the informations I have and the App closing, to me means that the whole object is gone and therefore it means that he is closing the main thread of Application.Run() - method?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler to the application. Running form on closing event may change some lifecycle such as application thread.

```
  private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
    Application.ApplicationExit += (obj, e) =>
    {
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    };
  }
```