# To Close the present Windows Form before navigating to Next Window

Tags: c#, winforms

I am in `Form1` Designer Window and  I have a `Button`. When I click on the `Button`,  I should navigate from `Form1` to `Form2`. However, `Form1` designer window should get closed.

In the below code when I click on the `Button`, `Form2` window will popup. **The issue is `Form1` will also be there on the computer screen along with `Form2`.** I wish to see only the window to which I would like to navigate,  and **the other should disappear**.

How to correct the below code accordingly?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
   Form2 Check = new Form2();
   Check.Show();  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# open a new form then close the current form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548746/c-sharp-open-a-new-form-then-close-the-current-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code hide `Form1` when you are showing `Form2` and then will close `Form1` when you close `Form2`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    Form2 Check = new Form2();
    Check.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
    Check.Show();
}
```

Comment: Great. Could you explain what is happening here in the line of code:    **Check.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();**

Comment: @GtR...`Hide()` will hide your main form and `Check.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();` will close main form after child form is closed. Your main form is still living after you show `Form2` so you should close it after closing `Form2`.

Comment: Check.Loaded+= (s, args) => this.Hide();