# Opeing/closing Windows Forms application running in Windows tablet?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio-2010

We have a simple Windows Forms application that will run in a Windows tablet. What we have so far is running well; the issue I'll be having is moving from winform to winform, and opening/closing Forms.

Currently, it looks something like this.

The following opens the main Form `FormHome`:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new FormHome());
}
```

A click in button from `FormHome` will then open a new Form call `FormInput`:

```
var form = new FormInput();
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
form.ShowDialog();
```

A click in `FormInput` will open yet another Form, `FormFeedback`:

```
var form = new FormFeedback(patientInputId);
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
form.ShowDialog();
```

And finally, `FormFeedback` will open one last final Form, `FormThanks`:

```
var form = new FormThanks();
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
form.ShowDialog();
```

`FormThanks` doesn't do anything; it just thanks the user and has a *Close* button. This means that this *Close* button will close `FormThanks`, `FormFeedback`, `FormInput`, so that the only Form I'll be seeing is `FormHome`.

Except for closing the winforms, everything else is working fine. But when I see the Forms that need to be opened/closed, I'm thinking that maybe it's better to use another architecture instead of the regular Windows Forms.

I was reading this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548746/c-sharp-open-a-new-form-then-close-the-current-form) and someone suggests to use an MDI containter and replace with panels instead. But my first thought is that I'll be seeing the FormBorder of the MDI container, plus the FormBorder of the child Form.

What are your thoughts? Should I switch to another architecture or just find a way to close all those Forms?

Thanks.

Comment: No, MDI never once made an app look or feel better.  Just write correct code, set the this.DialogResult property to DialogResult.OK after the ShowDialog() call so the dialog closes.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I close `FormFeedback`, `FormInput`, and display `FormHome` when I close `FormThanks`?

Comment: Well, it worked. I set `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` in all the Forms and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the .hide property. This will hide the forms you don't want to see and then you can use the .show to bring the ones you want forward. I hope i'm helping