# C# open a Form and close it

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show a Form called `TTT` so I tried this:

```
public static TTT ttt_local = new TTT();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ttt_local.Show();
}
```

Then I want to close the Form from inside so `ttt_local` closes itself when a button in `ttt_local` is pressed. That works but if I want to reopen `ttt_local` I get an `ObjectDisposedException`. Can someone help me please?

Comment: `ttt_local.Dispose();`

Comment: Show how you close the form. I guess you need is **hide** the form instead of **closing** it.

Comment: Never write code like this, a Form object is single-use.  Once it is closed then it is no longer usable.  And trying to use it again produces ODE.  Create the object when you need it.  If you want to enforce single-instance behavior then subscribe the FormClosed event to set the ttt_local variable back to null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# open a new form then close the current form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548746/c-sharp-open-a-new-form-then-close-the-current-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to let a form ***close*** itself, however you can set its visibility or simply ***hide*** it (the same also applies for ***showing*** a form):

Consumer-code:

```
var ttt = new TTT();
ttt.Show();
```

`TTT`-class:

```
public class TTT : Form
{    
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Now call `ttt.Show()` again within your *consumer-code*, not the form-class itself.

Alternativly you may set the visibility of the form using `Form.Visibility`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Use instance variable instead of class variable and let the things work as it is now.
2. Don't dispose the form, just live with `Show/Hide` options.

.

**Option 1:**

```
public TTT ttt_local = new TTT();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ttt_local == null) ttt_local = new TTT(); 
    ttt_local.Show();
}
```

**Option 2:**

Don't close the form, just play with `hide/show` or even set the `Visible` property.

Comment: obviously `ttt_local` will never be `null` as you set it at construction-time of the form. The check thus is meaningless.

Comment: I mean when the form is closed, one could set it to `null` so better to safe guard and create instance if it is not available.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason of using a global variable? You should only put the variable definition inside the event function:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TTT ttt_local = new TTT();
    ttt_local.Show();
}
```

Whenever the event is triggered, the variable creates and then it disposes with closing the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can show it and then hide it like that:

```
ttt_local.Show();
ttt_local.Hide();
```

or close:

```
ttt_local.Close();
```

Regards.