# what is the way to close the form and open it again

Tags: c#, timer, refresh

i try to close the from and open it again with this code bout it didn't close the form i found it in the background and open another one for it

```
private void Graph_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        timer1.Interval = 60000;//1 minutes
        timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Start();
    } 

 private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do whatever you want 
        RefreshMyForm();
    }


    private void RefreshMyForm()
    {
        this.Close();

        Graph1 graph = new Graph1();
        graph.Show();


    }
```

**start refresh is what i looking for**
    [image]

Comment: I don't think there is `this.close();` method with lower case `c`.

Comment: @SeM sorry i update my question thx

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# open a new form then close the current form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548746/c-sharp-open-a-new-form-then-close-the-current-form)

Comment: @SeM i want to do that to refresh my form

Comment: @SeM look for the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to change RefreshMyForm() to Refresh(); and clear function  RefreshMyForm().

```
    private void Graph_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

            timer1.Interval = 60000;//1 minutes
            timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        Refresh(); // OR Invalidate(); OR Update();
    }
```

Here label1 is simple watch to see how form refreshed every minute

Comment: your code refresh the label only not that form what i'm looking for is howa to refresh that form with the timer and close it and open it agyen to loud the data