# Winforms Application.Exit on Closing x app or clicking a Exit Button with a confirmation message

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, .net-4.7.2

I am developing a WinForms (.NET 4.7.2) application with *Telerik WinForm* (**2019.2.618.40**) controls.

On click of Close Box **[x]** icon on top tight of the window, I would like to ask for user confirmation and if YES only then close the app.

Following code works well, it closes the window, but it is **not** closing process (I can still see the app in *Task Manager*).

I believe I need to call `Application.Exit();` to kill the app process. But When I call that Closing Event is fired twice and I get confirmation window twice and gets following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified;
>   enumeration operation may not execute.'

How do I correct my closing event so that I can ask for user confirmation and close the windows as well as exit application cleanly from Task manager as well?

My Base Form

```
public class BaseForm : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
    {
        public BaseForm()
        {
           this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form_Closing);
        }
        public void Form_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        RadMessageBox.SetThemeName("Material");
        DialogResult dialogResult = RadMessageBox.Show(
                 this,
                 "Are you sure, you want to exit out of the application? Any unsaved data will be lost!",
                 "Application Name",
                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                 RadMessageIcon.Question,
                 MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2,
                 RightToLeft.No);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
            //Application.Exit();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }


     //....
     //....
     //....
    }
```

**Update**

---

instead of **FormClosign** Event if I use **FormClosed** event, `Application.Exit()` works fine, but on confirmation message if I click NO it is still closing app.

```
this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(App_kill);
```

App Kill Method (Cannot handle DialogResult.No response)

```
private void App_kill(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
            {
                RadMessageBox.SetThemeName("Material");
                DialogResult dialogResult = RadMessageBox.Show(
                         this,
                         "Are you sure, you want to exit out of the application? Any unsaved data will be lost!",
                         "Close Application",
                         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                         RadMessageIcon.Question,
                         MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2,
                         RightToLeft.No);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }

                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    //e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `RadMessageBox.Show`, `dialogResult` logic  and _then_ try to close the app. Does it kill the process?  (just in case Telerik is doing something odd)

Comment: I see your class is named `BaseForm`, are you deriving a child class from it that represents your application window?

Comment: @MickyD, yes if I remove RadMessageBox.Show it will kill process fine. Yes all my Forms are derived from BaseForm

Comment: Perhaps a bug with Telerik if used during the potential closure of a Window.  Perhaps it attaches to it and does some flunky modal processing?  You could use plain ol' WinForms `MessageBox.Show`, it may not look as pretty but it has equivalent funcationality for YesNo, Question etc.   I would probably lodge a bug report against Telerik

Comment: @MickyD same problem with MessageBox.Show, Problem here is this event is wired to FormClosing event. And when we call Application.Exit() it again calling FormClosing event, I think on Application.Exit() I should prevent triggering of FormClosing

Comment: Regarding your edit, you **cannot** prevent closure if you do your processing in `FormClosed`

Comment: _"same problem with MessageBox.Show"_ - unable to reproduce.  I suspect you have subscribed multiply to the `FormClosing` event.      This works **perfectly**:  `private void Form1_FormClosing(object s, FormClosingEventArgs e) { if (MessageBox.Show("Really close?", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.No) { e.Cancel = true;  }   }`.  Its not necessary to call either `Application.Exit` nor `Environment.Exit` as that is a hack

Comment: @MickyD can you please elaborate? I suspect you have subscribed multiply

Comment: In your constructor you subscribe to FormClosing, make sure you didn’t do it from the Designer too

Comment: Not sure who marked it for close. If they are confident, I can share my code and challenge them to share solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [nihique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75845/nihique) posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13459878/942855
and also pointed by [MickyD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/585968/mickyd) in this question comments.

Apparently there is no issue with my closing event. When I redirect from Form-A to Form-B, I had to do the following wiring and then it worked like a charm

```
 var newform = new myNewForm();
  newform.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
  this.Hide();
  newform.Show();
```

Comment: Probably would have been useful to mention you had two forms.  Glad you got it going nonetheless