# Open and close forms through a menu c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I've had a look around but none of the answers make any sense to me. I have a menu form which has buttons on; when users come to use the menu form, you can open other forms from the menu. Currently, I can get the form to open, but the menu form stays open too.

```
private void BtnAddNewCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
AddCompanyCar carForm = new AddCompanyCar();
carForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

The code above opens the form `AddCompanyCar` from the menu. How do I add to this code so that the form 'Menu' *closes* when `AddCompanyCar` *opens*?

Comment: I would recommend not to close it, but simply to hide it and unhide it when the user should return to the menu

Comment: What is the `Main` form of your project and how do you open the `Menu` form?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure want to do this as it impacts usability. If you're using WinForms, then just create a container window, and replace the panels instead. Might be easy and best way

If not and you wanna go-ahead, can take a look on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13459878/11109465)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hide it, then show it again when `ShowDialog()` returns?

```
private void BtnAddNewCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;

    AddCompanyCar carForm = new AddCompanyCar();
    carForm.ShowDialog(); // execution stops here until "carForm" is dismissed

    this.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by closing the main window, you destroy the context in which you were previously working. As others suggest, simply hide the main window so you can return to it.