# how to close only the main form in vb.net 2010 without terminating the application

Tags: vb.net

I have a login form which I need to close without the entire application being terminated. I tried using Me.Close() , Me.Hide() as well. The login form is used as the main form as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I close a login form and show the main form without my application closing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759334/how-can-i-close-a-login-form-and-show-the-main-form-without-my-application-closin)

Comment: It's impossible that calling a form's `Hide` method would cause your entire application to close. But of course, that's not the correct solution to your problem. You don't want the login form hanging around in memory for the entire lifetime of the app. Once the user has logged-in, they're done with it and don't ever need to see it again. You want to close it. My answer to the linked question above explains how to do this the *right* way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope this makes sense....

It sounds like you have a VB.Net project and your Login form is your 'startup form'.  When you close that form, your application thinks it is over; but you really want to take action after the Login form is closed.

If you bring up the Properties window for the project, on the Applications Tab you can set the '**Shutdown mode**'.  The default is when the 'Startup Form Closes'.  Change it to 'When the last form closes'.

You can also add Application level events here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2bys999(v=vs.80).aspx

If you stick with the way you are going; your Login form is going to have to create another form before it closes or your app will close.  You *can* do that; but it's probably cleaner to move the login logic into the Application Startup Event (see link for more details).

In the startup event you can show the Login screen, get the result, decide if you want to show the main form for your application, etc, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where you are trying to close or hide the form. If you are trying to close or hide the form from within the the form itself then Me.Close() and Me.Hide() does the job. If you are attempting to close or hide a form from another form like your main form then you must refer to the form instance example:

```
 frmAbout.Close()

 frmAbout.Hide()
```

I hope this helps.