# how to close this.form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 classes: Form1, LoginForm and program.

Program holds my main method that then runs loginform, if a condition inside login form is met then form1 is run.

What I want it to do is hide loginform just before I show form1.

How do I do this since I can't use loginform.hide();

Here's code:

```
namespace RepSalesNetAnalysis
{
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    public  bool letsGO = false;
    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static DataTable LookupUser(string Username)
    {
        const string connStr = "Server=10asaf;" +
                            "Database=dfafa;" +
                            "uid=bufaf;" +
                            "pwd=dridfsdf;" +
                            "Connect Timdf0;";

        //"Data Source=apex2006sql;Initial Catalog=Leather;Integrated Security=True;";

        const string query = "Select password From dbo.UserTable (NOLOCK) Where UserName = @UserName";
        DataTable result = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Username;
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    result.Load(dr);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textUser.Text))
        {
            //Focus box before showing a message
            textUser.Focus();
            MessageBox.Show("Enter your username", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            //Focus again afterwards, sometimes people double click message boxes and select another control accidentally
            textUser.Focus();
            return;
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textPass.Text))
        {
            textPass.Focus();
            MessageBox.Show("Enter your password", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            textPass.Focus();
            return;
        }

        //OK they enter a user and pass, lets see if they can authenticate
        using (DataTable dt = LookupUser(textUser.Text))
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                textUser.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username.", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textUser.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                string dbPassword = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Password"]);
                string appPassword = Convert.ToString(textPass.Text); //we store the password as encrypted in the DB
                //MessageBox.Show
                Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(dbPassword, appPassword));

                if (string.Compare(dbPassword, appPassword) == 0)
                {
                     DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                     this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    //You may want to use the same error message so they can't tell which field they got wrong
                    textPass.Focus();
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    textPass.Focus();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Am i missing something?  heres my main class;

```
namespace RepSalesNetAnalysis
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        LoginForm fLogin = new LoginForm();
        if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: did you try This.close() function..

Comment: `this.Hide();`​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I suggest moving all of the authentication code into a separate class.  Get it out of a form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steven this is all wrong ground up.

there are other ways to do what you need properly having the `Main` method of your `Program` class creating a login form and only if login is successful you instantiate and show the main application form.

check this question/answer for details and examples: [How can I close a login form and show the main form without my application closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759334/how-can-i-close-a-login-form-and-show-the-main-form-without-my-application-closi)

you in fact need this approach:

```
static void Main()
{
    LoginForm fLogin = new LoginForm();
    if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so i changed the main class program to your example,  when i hit the button on login form nothing happens,  because in the if statement im not actually doing anything.  what needs to go in there?

Comment: if login is successful close form by setting DialogResult to DialogResult.Ok, in the login form.

Comment: not sure i understand that.  in my loginform class, in the if statment where login is successfull, i need to say dialogresult.ok?

Comment: ok ive updated my post to show the changes. works fine. is this a hotfix? or is this the way you would do it?  i.e better OOP implementation.  reason i ask is because im very weak skilled when it comes to OOP

Answer (score 0):

```
static class Program
{
    private static bool canLogin;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        using (LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm()){
           // show as dialog
           // perform logic to check if successful
           canLogin = SomeStaticClass.VerifyCredentials(loginForm.Credentials);
           // grab any properties you may want here
        }
        //then run the application
        if(canLogin){
           Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: are you sure you can call a constructor with no '()' and there is no logic to check if login was really done and successful

Comment: the OP can provide the rest of the logic. Thanks for pointing out the missing `()` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can set `DialogResult` to `OK` or `Cancel` in your LoginForm. This will close your LoginForm and returns the DialogResult back to your Main method. Then check the result in your Main method like this.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    LoginForm form = new LoginForm();
    if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

**hope this helps**