# How to close multiple dialogs in the right way?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

I pasted the most important parts of my code below.

As you can see I'd like to work with multiple Forms. But this is how my Form behaves:

It opens Selector, when I press the second button it find the .ini file and opens ExplorerForm, but Selector IS STILL OPEN. Ofcourse I don't want that. I can't click the Selector, I just hear an error sound and the Explorer Window blinks. When I close the Explorer, both, the Explorer AND the Selector close.
But NOW the Path form opens...

When I press one of the other buttons in the Selector, it doesn't find the .INI file (that's right) and opens the Path form (and closes it in the right way).

I already used search and even implemented one of the answers there:

[How I can close a 1st form without closing the full application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639062/how-i-can-close-a-1st-form-without-closing-the-full-application)

My Program.cs:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Selector());
```

Selector.cs:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Path pathForm = new Path(0);
        this.Hide();
        pathForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Path pathForm = new Path(1);
        this.Hide();
        pathForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Path pathForm = new Path(2);
        this.Hide();
        pathForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Path.cs:

```
public Path(int currGame)
    {


        intGame = currGame;

        if(MyIni.KeyExists("Path"+intGame))
        {
        var GamePath = MyIni.Read("Path"+intGame);
            if(Directory.Exists(GamePath))
            {
                if (Directory.GetFiles(
                  GamePath, gameEXE(intGame), SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Count() > 0)
                {

                    InitializeComponent();



                    Explorer explorerForm = new Explorer();
                    this.Hide();
                    explorerForm.ShowDialog();
                    this.Hide();
                 }
            }
        }

        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = label1.Text + " " + gameString(currGame) + "!";
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
        RegistryKey sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(
              @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 12100"); 
              // III Steam
        RegistryKey sk2 = rk.OpenSubKey(
              @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 12110"); 
             // Vice City Steam
        RegistryKey sk3 = rk.OpenSubKey(
              @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 12120"); 
             // San Andreas Steam

        if(intGame == 0)
        {
            if (sk1 != null)
            {
                if (sk1.GetValueNames().Contains("InstallLocation") 
                && sk1.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString() != "")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = sk1.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();
                }
            }  
        }
        else if(intGame == 1)
        { 
        if(sk2 != null)
        {
            if(sk2.GetValueNames().Contains("InstallLocation") 
            && sk2.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString() != "")
            { 
            textBox1.Text = sk2.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();
            }
        }
        }
        else if (intGame == 2)
        {
            if (sk3 != null)
            {
                if (sk3.GetValueNames().Contains("InstallLocation") 
                 && sk3.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString() != "")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = sk3.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();
                }
            }
        }




    }
```

Comment: May you explain what is your expectation of when you open / close each form?

Comment: Anyway, you should use `Form.Show()` method instead of `ShowDialog()`. As the remaining code after `ShowDialog()` would be executed after the dialog closed, which seems not to be your expectation.

Comment: I see that you are closing the `Selector` form when one of the buttons is clicked. Since this is the main form (due to the line `Application.Run(new Selector())` this will kill the whole application. Is this intentionally? Maybe you can eleborate a bit more about you intentions. Since it isn't clear if you want to be able to open multiple windows or not, should the main window (the `Selector`) stay open or not, etc...

Comment: @MangoWong I don't want the forms to close all others.

Comment: @MangoWong When I close the Selector form it should ONLY close the swelector form, but not all forms :-) I don't want a MAIN form that closes all others :-)

Comment: You can start a new thread and run `Path` on it, so closing `Selector` form would not affect `Path` form. I would also like to know the your step-by-step expectation after clicking any button on `Selector` form. Would `Selector` be closed immediately? And what would be the behavior of `Explorer` form?

Comment: @MangoWong If you close one form via the X it should only close the current opened form.

Comment: @MangoWong If I open a new form with one of the buttons, the currently opened form should close and a new one should open.

Comment: Do you mean that at the beginning, there is only a Selector form. Then after pressing any buttons, specific `Path` form would pop-up and the `Selector` form would close? Would any two forms exist at the same time? And what is the use of `Explorer` form?

Comment: @MangoWong Explorer is the form that will be opened after selecting the path. No, there won't be any 2 forms at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modify involved code of your `Selector.cs` in this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.StartPathForm(1);
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.StartPathForm(2);
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.StartPathForm(3);
}
private void StartPathThread(int currGame)
{
    System.Threading.Thread pathThread = new System.Threading.Thread(PathThreadStart);
    pathThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
    pathThread.Start(currGame);
    this.Close();
}
private void PathThreadStart(object currGame) {
    Application.Run(new Path((int) currGame));
}
```

With this modification, a new thread would be initialized and the `Path` form will run on it. Then, the `Selector` form would close immediately. Hope this fit your use.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I fixed my code by my own an hour ago. I didn't know that only the first Window caused the others to exit. That's why I always use this piece of code now: explorerForm.Closed += (s, args) => Application.Exit();

Comment: But I hide all forms now instead of closing now. Doesn't matter, your solution works, too. That's why I select it as a working answer :-)

Comment: Why you would hide the forms instead of closing them if the forms are no longer used? For example, if you hide `Selector` form but not close it, the application thread would still be running. Therefore, even if you close the `Path` form later, the program would still be running. You would need further handling for this issue.

Comment: newForm.Closed += (s, args) => Application.Exit(); That's why I'm using this line of code everytime before opening a new form. If the newForm gets closed, it closes all currently opened forms, too. If it gets hidden, it doesn't do anything. :-)

Comment: I do not understand your program logic well, but it is glad that you fix the problem.