# How to hide or close startup loginform after main form is open?

Tags: c#, forms, authentication

After 6 hours of analyzing and following this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759334/how-can-i-close-a-login-form-and-show-the-main-form-without-my-application-closi) solution, my loginform frmLog still wont close. I created two forms in Microsoft visual studio C# window form application. My problem is even if I use different methods and tried everything the login form won’t close or hide. This is very annoying and cause me so much time just on this problem. Please help me.

this is my code in Program.cs where the start up form is initialize.

```
 public static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            frmLog fLogin = new frmLog();
            if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Application.Run(new frmMain());
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
```

And this is my login form code which shows the main form `frmMain` if the user and password is true they are actually connected to database.

```
 private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                Mylibrary a = new Mylibrary("localhost", "root", "", "cashieringdb");
                string user = txtLogin.Text;
                string pass = txtPassword.Text;
                string query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE username='" + user + "' AND password=MD5('" + pass + "')";
                int result = a.Count(query);
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    LOGIN_USER = txtLogin.Text;
                    frmMain main = new frmMain();
                    main.Show();
                    this.close
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Failed! Try Again");
                    txtLogin.Text = "";
                    txtPassword.Text = "";
                }

        }
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: You can Directly call frmMain form frmLogin right.? what you are trying to achieve with  fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL Injection using this code.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too I initialize login form `frmLog` to the main form and the problem is if the main for will show there is another login form that will show and everything keeps repeating.

Comment: no worry for sql injection I just want my freaking login form to be close. I am new to database so sql injection I will study it later after I finish this program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
  static void Main()


{
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmLog ());

    }
```

inside frmlog

use

```
this.hide();
new frmMain().ShowDialog();
```

Comment: DUDE you are my angel now I realize my mistake I actually tried this code but I put the new `frmMain` first before `this.Hide();`

Comment: Really suggesting .Hide() in this situation? Seriously? The login should be closed altogether, not just hidden from the sight.

Comment: @walther since login form is my startup form, if I will close my mainform the loginform will be closed too and I already tried it.

Comment: @user2262382, that doesn't matter, because there's no reason for loginform to still exist during the whole lifetime of your application.

Comment: @walther yup all important is I can still no longer see that form when my main form starts thanks anyway for the advice.

Comment: @walther, i would be happy to see a better solution

Answer (score 0):

`loginform login = new loginfrom();
login.Hide();`

Please try this way your login form hide.

Answer (score 0):

Your login form shouldn't be responsible for showing the main form, that is already handled later in your `Main` method! What you should do instead is to return the DialogResult, because later you're checking for its value.

I rather won't comment on your code, because it's an architectural suicide. Mixing various layers into one ugly mess, yuck.

The accepted answer suggesting `.Hide()` as a solution is **BAD**. Hide() is an equivalent of saying `.Visible=false`, that doesn't make sense in your scenario. It would still exist in the background.

Comment: yes I am actually  just a student I am new to everything this C# and mysql database everything is new to me :D

Comment: @user2262382, that's all nice, but if you were a building architect, you wouldn't put a toilet in the middle of the entrance hall, would you? It's kinda the same thing. You should learn good practices from the beginning or else you will have problems later.

Comment: @user2262382, yea, couldn't resist. You've selected the wrong answer though... Hiding the form isn't really a good idea. Maciej just posted a better answer.

Comment: I pinned my form on my taskbar and if it really still on the background the popup icon on the taskbar should still active but in my case it doen't popup anymore so, that means the form is totaly close.

Answer (score 0):

Modify `Main()` as default:

```
 static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmLog ());
    }
```

Use `this.Hide();` instead of `this.Close();`,try this:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Mylibrary a = new Mylibrary("localhost", "root", "", "cashieringdb");
            string user = txtLogin.Text;
            string pass = txtPassword.Text;
            string query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE username='" + user + "' AND password=MD5('" + pass + "')";
            int result = a.Count(query);
            if (result == 1)
            {
                LOGIN_USER = txtLogin.Text;
                frmMain main = new frmMain();
                main.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed! Try Again");
                txtLogin.Text = "";
                txtPassword.Text = "";
            }

    }
```

Comment: I feel that this might lead to memory leak. The **frmLog** keeps hidden in the memory even if the **frmMain** form is closed. So apparently the application would be running in the memory even if we quit it.

Answer (score 0):

Your login form should be a separate one and you should show it as dialog from your main form. Your code could look like this:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool loginSuccessful = false;
    var frmLogin = new FormLogin();
    while (frmLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // verify login details
        Mylibrary a = new Mylibrary("localhost", "root", "", "cashieringdb");
        string user = frmLogin.txtLogin.Text;
        string pass = frmLogin.txtPassword.Text;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE username='" + user + "' AND password=MD5('" + pass + "')";
        int result = a.Count(query);
        if (result != 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login failed, try again", "Login");
        }
        else
        {
            loginSuccessful = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!loginSuccessful)
    {
        // user cancelled - close main window to end application
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Q/A suggested that You started correctly.
From `Main()` call `LoginForm` as modal and if result is OK `LoginForm` is automatically closed and MainForm is run by `ApplicationRun(MainForm)`.

But, You allready called `MainForm` from `LoginForm`.

```
if (result == 1)
{
  LOGIN_USER = txtLogin.Text;
  frmMain main = new frmMain();
  main.Show();
  this.close
}
```

so change it with:

```
if (result == 1)
{
  LOGIN_USER = txtLogin.Text;
  //Logged in
  // return DialogResult.OK as it needed for Program.cs to allow load MainForm
  this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

[Modal Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) - "...the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is **closed**..."

Answer (score 0):

You don't need hide first window when you show next window. Just in the Main method of Program class in the Program.cs file do this steps:

```
static void Main()
{
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length > 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MyFirstWindow fw = null;
        do
        {
            fw = new MyFirstWindow();
            Application.Run(fw);
        } while (!fw.checked);

        Application.Run(new MyNextWindow());
    }
```

As you see in the MyFirstWindow class you have isChecked property which type is boolean and default value is false. So you can do some checks (login for example), change value of the checked property and close the first window. Your next window will not run untill the checked property will not be true