# C#: Close and Open two forms from a separate form

Tags: c#, forms, hide, show

I have 3 forms. How can I make it so that one form is shown with .Show() and the other is hidden with .Hide() from a separate form?

This is part of my code

```
    private void buttonYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoggedIn loggedinform = new LoggedIn();
        loggedinform.Hide(); // Hides another form that is in the background
        MainForm mainform = new MainForm();
        mainform.Show(); // Show first form
        this.Hide(); // Hides current form
    }
```

One problem, the LoggedIn form does not hide itself. From the looks of it it skips it and just goes for the mainform.Show();

Is this a bug or do I need to do something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I close a login form and show the main form without my application closing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759334/how-can-i-close-a-login-form-and-show-the-main-form-without-my-application-closi)

Comment: I've looked through it and it deals with his form not showing up, while mine doesn't want to hide. I'm still stumped because it should work. I don't understand why it skips over it when the form is present on the desktop, and not closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `LoggedIn loggedinform = new LoggedIn()` is going to create a new instance of that login window. That might be useful if, say, you intended to show 5 "Login" windows onscreen all at once. I think what you want to do is retrieve a reference to the login window that is already showing, and hide that; so, avoid creating a new one.

Properly passing references to existing objects around the program is kind of a structural problem, and one that I ran into quite a bit in my early programming days. The quick, unclean, and generally not-recommended way is to declare instances of those singular objects (like, maybe, your login window) as `static`, so they can be retrieved anywhere. However, to fully answer your question in the best way, maybe you could describe the structure of your program a bit more (full code isn't necessary, just generally-speaking, what the flow is between classes)

Comment: My program has no classes as of now because I'm still new to C#. But what the program is, when you start it you have a login form with a password and username by a database dictionary located in a .bin file, if you login correctly the form will hide and the new one will show, the "LoggedIn" form and from there you can click "LogOut" which brings up a confirm window with yes or no, and the code I provided is for the yes button. The LoggedIn form is supposed to close and the other Login form from before is supposed to pop up, which it does, but the current form in the background doesn't close.

Comment: @nurtul If you think that your program does not have classes (er...wrong), you may need a bit more of a primer than I can give in a single answer. To speed you along: A "class" is like a blueprint for an object. An "object" is a constructed instance of that object. Forms are objects, created through the classes (code files) you write in code. If you create (`object = new MyClass()`) more of them than you need, then there's confusion. Maybe try Googling "C# class object tutorial".

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I can use

```
        Application.OpenForms[1].Hide();
```

[1] is the form I'm trying to hide. And it worked.

I also realized thanks to Katana that it makes sense why it wasn't working because it was basically making a new instance of the form instead of finding the current one. Sorry that my code is a mess.

Comment: Actually Application.OpenForms.OfType<LoggedIn>().First().Close(); to be more exact. Because Application.OpenForms[1].Hide(); only works once since the form number changes once hidden.