# Losing variable value when changing forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a very simple program, to help figure out how to use multiple forms in C#. I have Form1(**form1**), and Form2(**form2**). On form1 I have a button, a label, and a Serial Port. On form2 I have a button, and a label. What the program does, is when I click the button it closes that form opens the other, changes the text in the label, and then changes the BaudRate. Here is the code for form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Making a refernce of Form2 called 'form2'.
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Able to reference form2 in a style that replicated VB.NET
        form2.Show();
        this.Hide();
        form2.label2.Text = ("Hello2");
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = ("Start!");
        ApplicationPort.BaudRate = 200;
    }
```

Here is the code for form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Declaring the new instance of Form1 called 'form1'.
        var form1 = new Form1();     
        this.Hide();
        form1.Show();
        form1.label1.Text = ("hello");
        MessageBox.Show(form1.ApplicationPort.BaudRate.ToString());
    }

    public void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Declaring the new instancce for Form1 called 'form1'.
        var form1 = new Form1();
        MessageBox.Show(form1.ApplicationPort.BaudRate.ToString());

    }
}
```

So what is happening, is when I start the program the BaudRate is **200**. When I click the button, and the second form opens, in the load event I have the message box showing the BaudRate as **9600**, the default value. Then when I click the button in form2, the message box shows the original BaudRate of **200**. Why is it that the Load event handler isnt getting the value? Am I writing the referencing, or something wrong? I am working with Visual Studio 2010 Express WinForms.

Comment: I'm sorry if this appears lazy, but my answer to this question may help you figure out what's causing this behavior; it seemed very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196511/c-close-and-open-two-forms-from-a-separate-form/18196591#18196591

Comment: You are creating a new instance of Form1 from form2.

Comment: What is the definition of ApplicationPort object in Form1?

Comment: For the love of those following you, please stop using names like `Form1` and `Form2`.

Comment: @AustinSalonen this program was thrown together in about 5 minutes, just made quick and easy names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var form1 = new Form1();
    MessageBox.Show(form1.ApplicationPort.BaudRate.ToString());
```

With this you are creating **new** instance of `Form1` which will have  all settings set to default values.

You need to pass your existing instance of `Form1` object to the newly created `Form2` object.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1;
    public Form2(Form1 frm)
    {
        form1 = frm;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Declaring the new instance of Form1 called 'form1'.
        //var form1 = new Form1();     
        this.Hide();
        form1.Show();
        form1.label1.Text = ("hello");
        MessageBox.Show(form1.ApplicationPort.BaudRate.ToString());
    }

    public void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Declaring the new instancce for Form1 called 'form1'.
        MessageBox.Show(form1.ApplicationPort.BaudRate.ToString());

    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Making a refernce of Form2 called 'form2'.
    Form2 form2; // Pass the instance of this object to Form2!

    public Form1()
    {
        form2 = new Form2(this)
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Able to reference form2 in a style that replicated VB.NET
        form2.Show();
        this.Hide();
        form2.label2.Text = ("Hello2");
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = ("Start!");
        ApplicationPort.BaudRate = 200;
    }
```

Comment: When I try to implement this into the code, I get the error **Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context** at `Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);`

Comment: Works out perfectly, and I somewhat understand it! Thank you.

Comment: For those who are getting here: it does not work in 2024.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of Form1 from Form2. You could pass Form1 to the Form2 constructor.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1 = form1;
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        this.Hide();
        form1.Show();
        form1.label1.Text = ("hello");
        MessageBox.Show(form1.ApplicationPort.BaudRate.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to save the value of baud rate, you must declare a `static` property like this:

```
public static int baudRate = 200;
```

in your form which contains SerialPort control.

then use assign `buadRate` to `SerialPort` in your form constructor.