# c# - login form won't close

Tags: c#, authentication

I am working on a project (simple phonebook) for personal use.

Basically, I have got three forms: **Main** (the main one), **Settings** (the one used for configuring settings) and **Login** (the login form, which should start only if the user checked the option to be asked for the password on startup). Just to make the things clear: when the .EXE file is started it should load the **Main** form, unless the option to ask for pass is checked (**Properties.Settings.Default.AskForPass == true**) - when it should run the **Login** form first.

Here is what the login form looks like:

[image: Login]

I have no idea how to make things work in the proper way.

I have tried to change the line in **Program.cs** from **Main** to **Login**:

```
namespace Phonebook
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Login());
        }
    }
}
```

and then if the user enters the right username and password and clicks the OK button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUsername.Text == Properties.Settings.Default.MyUsername && txtPassword.Text == Properties.Settings.Default.MyPassword)
        {
            Main f1 = new Main();
            Login f3 = new Login();
            f1.Show();
            f3.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Wrong password! Do you want to try again?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                return;
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

the login form stays in the background, as you can see here:

[image: Contacts]

I would like the **Login** form to be closed, so it doesn't appear in the background. The problem is that now the **Login** form is the main one and if I try to close it, the whole application shuts down.

I have tried changing the owner but had no success doing so.

Any ideas? Please, help!

Comment: Check here if it helps you . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759334/how-can-i-close-a-login-form-and-show-the-main-form-without-my-application-closi

Comment: `f1` and `f3` is confusing. If you have more than one variable in a block, it is helpful to use more descriptive names like `formMain` and `formLogin`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new Login form and closing that.  Try

```
this.Hide();
f1.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

Another approach is to return a status on the Login Form and then check that and Application.Run() the Main form:

In the login form:

```
private bool LoggedIn;
public bool IsLoggedIn { get { return LoggedIn; } }
```

Then in the button click:

```
LoggedIn = true; 
this.Close();
```

And in Program.cs:

```
Login f = new Login();
Application.Run(f);

if (f.IsLoggedIn)
    Application.Run(new Main());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works fine. But, I want form **Main** to be the main one, and now that is not the case. Now, the main one is **Login**. How can I make the **Login** form appears first (only if Properties.Settings.Default.AskForPass == true), while form **Main** is actually the main one?

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. I have added `if (Properties.Settings.Default.AskForPass == true)` as well.