# Why code in the wrong form is ran after starting the application?

Tags: c#, forms

I am currently coding a login Window for my tool.

My tool is made in Form1 while Form2 is my login.

Now while started to debug, for whatever reason it went to Form1 straight.

[image: This is the Beginning code after "namespace".]

I tried removing Form2 completely and remaking it, same problem persists though. I have no idea what to do now.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I edited your title to make it clearer and easier to find an answer to a similar problem in the future. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: `WebClient` needs to be `Dispose()`'ed. You should not make that a class level field, or, you need to handle disposing it when you are done with the form.

Comment: Name your forms meaningfully. Don't call them Form1 and Form2. Call them LoginForm, MenuForm, MainForm, something like that. Give them appropriate names. And check your Program.cs file to see which is going to be run. Also, check your project's properties for what your startup object is. It should not be set. Or set to Program.cs.

Comment: You're going to need to know how Program.cs works, otherwise you may encounter further errors when you try to move from your LoginForm to your MainForm. If you find that the program ends upon trying to move from one to the other, then you'll have to code Program.cs differently. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759334/how-can-i-close-a-login-form-and-show-the-main-form-without-my-application-closi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `Program.cs` class and its `Main()` method. You probably have such a line there:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Change it to

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: @CodeCaster OP wrote that Form2 is the login form.

Comment: Fixed it for me, thank you!